Book about a colony ship making an unscheduled stop in a star system with no habitable planets
I read a book about a colony ship that experienced some malfunctions and had to make an unscheduled stop in a star system with no habitable planets and a gas giant where the habitable zone would be.
The colonists have the ability to freeze themselves and also be immortal basically. So they start taking shifts redirecting small moons of this gas giant into one, somewhat larger moon, that can keep an atmosphere long enough for them to build the facilities to build the fuel or whatever they needed.  I think it was antimatter.
To do this they start waking up some colonists and the colonists have kids and their kids have kids and soon they've built an entire civilization. The original colonists are basically gods and their descendants aren't really even considered worthy of bringing with them to the original destination.  The problem is the star is a red dwarf and solar flares wreck the atmosphere badly, so eventually they fabricate a giant lightning rod on a close in hot earth to redirect the solar flares away from the orbital plane.

Parts of this are reminiscent of Robert Reed's Marrow (a short story later expanded into a book): immortal humans and building a civilization from descendants, but the ship was the gas giant and the planet was at the core of that.

So they can't use spacesuits and remote controlled robots to do repairs?  So they can't build a civilization based on artificial space habitats to do repairs?  So they have do the repairs on the surface of a habitable world?

M.A. I'm not sure exactly why they didn't use robots, it's been a few years since I read it, but it might have been a literary conceit to make the story about the morality of the situation more clear

Possibly "Building Harlequin's Moon" by Niven and Cooper.

The John Glenn creates a substantial moon around the gas giant Harlequin by colliding several smaller moons together, and give it an atmosphere, seas, and the beginnings of an ecosystem. This takes 60,000 years, with almost all the passengers of the ship in hibernation during the entire time.

The source also mentions radiation flares, antimatter, and that "the moon-born are being treated as slaves".

That was it! I kept getting the main character confused with the one from Mary Caraker's Faces of Ceti and it was driving me nuts!

I haven't actually read it - I kind of gave up on late Niven - but I might give it a whirl.

The book is more Brenda Cooper's heavy lifting than it is Larry Niven.
